# Hazelcast cluster getting jvm out of memory leak with cache

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks, hazelcast

I have integrated hazelcast 3.11 as distributed cluster. And i have used it for the cache the json files. I haven't configured any maximum values so it is just default settings. 
Problem is when I feed 1M data to this cache it fails with JVM crashes on the nodes in the cluster.

This works fine when we restart the nodes of course.

Comment: put more details. What is the setup Client server or embeded for hazelcast. Who is throwing OutOfMemory the server or the client. How much memory is allocated to the server (Hazelcast) how much to the client. More detailes please.

Comment: Also how do you insert the file. Do you insert it as Binary , do you insert it as object.... how ?

Comment: What interface do you use, IMap... or ?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply @AlexandarPetrov.. It is client server..Memory is enough for this i.e. 2gb...It stores the json files in terms of object in the cache.. And I use interface as IMap

Comment: what do you mean by jvm crashes ? Is it throwing out of memory or another type of exception.  Do you observe anything in the logs ? Is it the client that us crashing or is it the server. How many servers are setup. Is only one node crashing or the complete cluster. Details... details.... You are too broad.

Comment: Please edit your question to add requested details.